# How to bcp out a few columns instead of all the columns? (Sybase)

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How to bcp out only a few columns from a Sybase (Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0) table? The following is the Sybase bcp help screen. It doesn't accept an SQL as input. I want to bcp out all the columns of the unique indexes for many tables. Or is there any alternative way?

```
usage: bcp [[db_name.]owner.]table_name[:slice_num] [partition pname] {in | out}
 [filename]
        [-m maxerrors] [-f formatfile] [-e errfile] [-d discardfileprefix]
        [-F firstrow] [-L lastrow] [-b batchsize]
        [-n] [-c] [-t field_terminator] [-r row_terminator]
        [-U username] [-P password] [-I interfaces_file] [-S server]
        [-a display_charset] [-z language] [-v]
        [-i input_file] [-o output_file]
        [-A packet size] [-J client character set]
        [-T text or image size] [-E] [-g id_start_value] [-N] [-W] [-X]
        [-M LabelName LabelValue] [-labeled]
        [-K keytab_file] [-R remote_server_principal] [-C]
        [-V [security_options]] [-Z security_mechanism] [-Q] [-Y]
        [-y sybase directory] [-x trusted.txt_file]
        [--clienterr errfile] [--maxconn maximum_connections]
        [--show-fi] [--hide-vcc]
        [--colpasswd [[[db_name.[owner].]table_name.]column_name [password]]]
        [--keypasswd [[db_name.[owner].]key_name [password]]]
        [--initstring ASE initialization string] [--quoted-fname]
```

The version is `Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0/EBF 20305 SMP ESD#01 Refresh#2/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux//2927/64-bit/FBO/Fri Jun 22 09:38:01 2012`

Comment: Create a formatfile and provide it to the `-f` parameter...? At least that is how it works in sybase's sister database SqlServer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337558%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Can format file be used when bcp out too?

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine why it shouldn't but I'm a wanna be DBA (aka developer) so I might be mistaken...

Comment: format files are notoriously tricky in Sybase, better off using views.  BTW - you are realy using Sybase ASA, or is that supposed to be ASE?  Also, what version are you using.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Sybase ASE prior to version 15.5, then your best option is to [create views](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X30101.htm) on the tables that match the columns you wish to extract, then you can `bcp` out of those views.

```
create view titles_view 
as select title, type, price, pubdate 
from titles

bcp mydatabase..titles_view out titles_view -Uusername -Sservername -n
```

If you are using SAP Sybase ASE 15.5 or newer, you can use the `output` command to output the results of a select statement to a file.

```
select *
from employee
go
output to employee.txt
format ASCII
```

The syntax and options for `output` can be found here:  [Sybase ASE Reference Manual: Commands](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/BABDABGE.htm)

Comment: Does `output to` work well with very big table? Can it output to network shared drive?

Comment: The version is "Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0/EBF 20305 SMP ESD#01 Refresh#2/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux//2927/64-bit/FBO/Fri Jun 22 09:38:01 2012"

Comment: Honestly, I haven't had good luck using output, so I don't know about performance or network drive options.  It uses the GUI version of isql, and I primarily use the CLI version of isql.

Comment: `output to` doesn't sound like a tool for automation if it uses the GUI version of isql to export data.

Comment: As I recall, the gui verison can run non-interactively (I think it's called batch mode).  It's not entirely user dependent.

Comment: I tried `select top 10 * from table\n 
go\n
output to test format ascii' in Rapid Sql. And it always gets error of "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'output'". Is it a command of sybase ISql only?

Comment: IDK.  I only use Sybase utils, so I don't know the features for other tools.